# templateUrl angularJs Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am e newbie to angularJs and rails and i am trying to render a template from directive using "templateUrl" as follow:
carts.js

```
angular.module("cart", [])
.factory("cart", function () {
var cartData = [];
return {
    addProduct: function (id, name, price) {
        var addedToExistingItem = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
            if (cartData[i].id == id) {
                cartData[i].count++;
                addedToExistingItem = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!addedToExistingItem) {
            cartData.push({
                count: 1, id: id, price: price, name: name
            });
        }
    },
    removeProduct: function (id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
        if (cartData[i].id == id) {
            cartData.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
},
getProducts: function () {
    return cartData;
}
}
})
 .directive("cartSummary", function (cart) {
   return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "templates/cart.html",
      controller: function ($scope) {
         var cartData = cart.getProducts();
         $scope.total = function () {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                total += (cartData[i].price * cartData[i].count);
            }
            return total;
         }
         $scope.itemCount = function () {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                total += cartData[i].count;
            }
            return total;
         }
     }
   };
 });
```

assets/templates/cart.html

```
<style>
 .navbar-right { float: right !important; margin-right: 5px;}
  .navbar-text { margin-right: 10px; }
</style>
<div class="navbar-right">
 <div class="navbar-text">
  <b>Your cart:</b>
  {{itemCount()}} item(s),
  {{total() | currency}}
 </div>
 <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Checkout</a>
</div>
```

and in aplication.html.erb i added thois line

```
<cart-summary />
```

but i do not get the dispalyed data into cart.html

so what should i put into templateUrl?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not putting view templates under the Rails Asset pipeline.  There are just a number of routing and loading issues that you will have to account for.

Rather, I would (and this is what my dev group does) create a TemplatesController to serve the view templates.  Basically, you will only need a `show` action (and a `index` for your root route if desired).

**templates_controller.rb**

```
class TemplatesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def show
        render "templates/#{params[:path]}", layout: nil
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'templates/*path' => 'template#show'
    # ... other routes ...
end
```

Your templates will now be served by a Rails controller.

ADDENDUM:

Sorry, but this is bad, especially for a directive:

```
<style>
    .navbar-right { float: right !important; margin-right: 5px;}
    .navbar-text { margin-right: 10px; }
</style>
```

If you need to add styles to elements inside of the directive template, and you don't want to put it in a external css file, add the styles via the `link` function:

```
link: function(scope, el, attr) {
    el.find('.navbar-right').css({float: "right !important", margin-right: "5px"});
    el.find('.navbar-text').css("margin-right", "10px")
}
```